# Oxyplot - Get visible Points

Tags: c#, .net, oxyplot

I'm using OxyPlot to draw a huge amount of data in a StairStepSeries. The performance is good, but very bad if I'm activating Markers. Therefore I would like to implement a check: Markers can only be activated if a certain number of visible points are not exceeded.

Is it possible to get only the number of visibile points? I found no solution. I get only the total number of points of a chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this myself.

```
public int GetNumberOfVisiblePointsOnScreen(StairStepSeries stairStepSeries)
{
    int numberOfVisiblePointsOnScreen = 0;
    foreach (DataPoint point in stairStepSeries.Points) {
        if (stairStepSeries.GetScreenRectangle ().Contains (stairStepSeries.Transform (point)))
            numberOfVisiblePointsOnScreen++;
    }
    return numberOfVisiblePointsOnScreen;
}
```

GetScreenRectangle() method will give the Rectangle the series currently uses on the screen. Loop through all the DataPoints inside your StairStepSeries and check if it is in the Current screen rectangle.