# OxyPlot performance issue on larg data in WPF on InvalidatePlot

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I'm using OxyPlot in my wpf application as line recorder. It's like the [LiveDemo](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/tree/master/Source/Examples/WPF/WpfExamples/Examples/LiveDemo) example.
On a larg visible data set, I get some UI performance issues and may the whole application could freez. It seems to be PlotModel.InvalidatePlot which is called with to many points to often, but I didn't found a better way.

### In deep:

- Using OxyPlot 2.0.0
- I code all in the PlotModel. The Xaml PlotView is only binding to the PlotModel.
- I cyclical collect data in a thread an put them in a DataSource (List of List  which are ItemSoure for the LineSeries)
- I have a class which calculates cyclical in a thread the presentation for x and y axis and a bit more. After all this stuff, it calls PlotModel.InvalidatePlot.

If I

- have more than 100 k points on the display (no matter if in multiple LineSeries or not)
- and add 1 DataPoint per LineSeries every 500 ms
- and call PlotModel.InvalidatePlot every 200 ms

not only the PlotView has performance issues, also the window is very slow in reaction, even if I call PlotModel.InvalidatePlot (false).

## My goal

My goal would be that the Windo / Application is working normally. It should not hang up because of a line recorder. The best would be if it has no performance issues, but I'm skeptical.

### What I have found or tested

OxyPlot has [Performance guidelines](https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guidelines/performance.html). I'm using ItemsSource with DataPoints. I have also tried adding them directly to the LineSeris.Points, but then the Plot doesn’t refresh anyway (even with an ObservableCollection), so I have to call PlotModel.InvalidatePlot, what results in the same effect. I cannot bind to a defined LineSeries in Xaml because I don’t know how much Lines will be there. Maybe I missed something on adding the points directly?

I have also found a Github issue [1286](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/1286) which is describing a related problem, but this workaround is slower in my tests.

I have also checked the time which is elapsed on the call of PlotModel.InvalidatePlot, but the count of points does not affect it.

I have checked the UI thread and it seems it have trouble to handle this large set of points

[image: LargepointSet]

If I zoom in to the plot and display under 20 k Points it looks so

[image: Zoomed]

## Question:

**Is there a way to handle this better, except to call PlotModel.InvalidatePlot much less?**

#### Restrictions:

I also must Update Axis and Annotations. So, I think I will not come around to call PlotModel.InvalidatePlot.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that using the OxyPlot Windows Forms implementation and then displaying it using Windows Form integration in WPF gives much better performance.

e.g.

```
var plotView = new OxyPlot.WindowsForms.PlotView();
plotView.Model = Plot;

var host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
host.Child = plotView;

PlotContainer = host;
```

Where 'Plot' is the PlotModel you call InvalidatePlot() on.

And then in your XAML:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding PlotContainer}"/>
```

Or however else you want to use your WindowsFormsHost.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and found that you can use a `Decimator` in `LineSeries`. It is documented in the examples: [LineSeriesExamples.cs](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/Examples/ExampleLibrary/Series/LineSeriesExamples.cs)

The usage is like this:

```
public static PlotModel WithXDecimator()
{
  var model = new PlotModel { Title = "LineSeries with X Decimator" };
  var s1 = CreateSeriesSuitableForDecimation();
  s1.Decimator = Decimator.Decimate;
  model.Series.Add(s1);
  return model;
}
```

This may solve the problem on my side, and I hope it helps others too. Unfortunately it is not documented in the [documentation](https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I ended up with calculating the time for calling InvalidatePlot for the next time. I calculate it with the method given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41195732/7790628), wich returns the number of visible points. This rededuce the performance issue, but dosent fix the block on the UI Thread on calling InvalidatePlot.